# Why is a newly created checkbox checked when I set checked to false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

When I put this code in my console, I end up with a checked box in my web page:

```
$('body').append($('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    value: "foo",
    checked: false
}));
```

When I remove the checked attr altogether, the box is not checked:

```
$('body').append($('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    value: "foo",                                                                  
}));
```

...but I need a dynamic set of checkboxes to be generated, some checked and some not. What attr/value creates the correct "unchecked" state?

UPDATE:

I am using the latest Chrome.
jQuery version 3.2.1
The code works as expected in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmvunhL0/
But not on my website... I'm wondering if there is a global setting or something touching the checkbox behavior.

Comment: What browser are you using? You're first example works for me in chrome/IE

Comment: I'm using latest Chrome

Comment: using SO's version of jQuery (1.12) both examples append an unchecked checkbox.

Comment: XHTML allows checked to have a value. In HTML the `checked` attribute doesn't allow a value. I

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/g73c17wh/

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: using:  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: Weird, it works in this JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmvunhL0/ , but not in my dev environment

Comment: Are you sure you aren't trying `checked: 'false'`?

Comment: @Pat: `checked: 'false'` will cause that checkbox will be checked.

Comment: I am not using the string false, but the bool false, like my code shows.

Comment: @JacobIRR: for checked inputs use `checked: true`, for unchecked nothing (or `checked: false` as you have now, without quotes around).

Comment: @panther - I guess that's all I can do. Would accept that as the answer .

Comment: @panther - It's just odd that it works as expected on jsfiddle, and differently on my site with the same version of JQ

Comment: @JacobIRR: can you add a link to your site? We can debug it there.

Comment: @panther - no its running on localhost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161136/discussion-between-jacobirr-and-panther).

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, and I've checked the values and they are either true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .prop or .attr for the checkbox

```html
<div id="body">

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>   
var value = true;

$('#body').append($('<input/>', {
                                    type: 'checkbox',
                                    value: "foo",
                                }).prop('checked', value) ) ;
                                
value = false;                                
$('#body').append($('<input/>', {
                                    type: 'checkbox',
                                    value: "foo",
                                }).prop('checked', value) );   
                                
</script>
```

Comment: Not exactly necessary to chain the method.

Answer (score 3):

When used with the checkbox, the attribute `checked` is a boolean attribute.

If it exists at all then it is true.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

is the same as

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="false" />
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

The only way to not have it checked is by not having the `checked` attribute at all.

Comment: In JS `checked: false` is correctly used as OP has. There is difference between `checked: false` and `checked: "false"`.

Comment: @panther is correct. I am following the rules of the API and `checked:false` should result in an unchecked box.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting unchecked on both of your code. Because, by default the checkbox is unchecked and if you want it to be checked explicitly, then define checked to true.

```
$('body').append($('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    value: "foo",
    checked: true
}));
```

---

If you want it randomly, then you can use Math:

```
$('body').append($('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    value: "foo",
    checked: Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()))
}));
```

Boolean is necessary here. It's because the property value strictly look for true of false value but not truthy or falsy value.

Comment: @mhodges That's html and in html if you just define checked attribute then that is identified by true status.